# how do I know which package manager in installed on my linux

Tags: linux, yocto

I've received a linux-yocto box.  I now I'm trying to installing some software, on ubuntu I use apt-get but it seems not to work/installe. so I've tried yum same  result.
so my question is, is there a way to find out which package manager is install on my linux system ?

thanks in advance !

Comment: You don't. You have to know that beforehand. You can test all possible to find out if one exists, but that doesn't mean anything either (I can install `dpkg` and `apt-get` on my archlinux, but it uses `pacman` anyway). Yocto comes without a package manager, I think, or you can install one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yocto is using either rpm, dpkg, or opkg as the package manager.  *If* the tools are installed on the image, which isn't a requirement, then the binaries are either `dnf` (or `yum` if it is a really old release), `apt-get`, or `opkg` respectively.

There's a reasonable chance that you've been given an image without a package manager or a working feed though.  The joy of Yocto is that it is so flexible, so you should ask whoever gave you the software.

Comment: You missed at least `portage` which is used by Gentoo

Comment: Portage may be used by Gentoo but it isn't used by Yocto, so I don't see how that's relevant.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it could be any package manager. Never used Yocto. Edited to make it more clear. If you don't like the edit, feel free to rollback